# Finding the location of a TD in a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So let's say I have a table, and I want to manipulate a specific `<td>` in it:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td> <td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="hi">5</td> <td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[2].cells[0];
```

This will help me REACH a specific cell in a table.

My question is this:

Say I have a specific `<td>` inside a table:

```
var td = document.getElementById("hi")
```

I want to KNOW its location in the table, so I can be able to reach it using `table.rows[x].cells[y]`
How can I check this location?

Comment: `if(table.rows[x].cells[y].id == "hi")...` either that or compare objects: `td === table.rows[x].cells[y]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest, as you imply you know which specific cell you want to find, though currently untested:

```
var td = document.getElementById("hi"),
    col = td.cellIndex,
    row = td.parentNode.rowIndex;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Took me quite some time to test cross-browser.

Comment: But only because I didn't bother to do a cross-browser check (I was, though, *fairly* confident that both were supported across most browsers)

Comment: I just want to make sure. Can't find it anywhere but w3fools.com

Answer (score 4):

The `cellIndex` property of a `td` element gives the index of the cell in the row.
The `rowIndex` property of a `tr` element gives the index of the row in the table.

So,

```
var td = document.getElementById("hi");
var x = td.cellIndex;
var y = td.parentNode.rowIndex;
```

Comment: While semicolons are optional in JavaScript, if you use this code they'll be automagically 'added,' which means that the variables `x` and `y` will be in the global scope (unless I'm misunderstanding something), you may want to use commas.

Comment: @DavidThomas Good call. Old habit (sigh)

Answer (score 2):

You will need something like this:

```
function getRowCellPosition(table, cell) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            if (table.rows[i].cells[j] === cell) {
                return {
                    row: i,
                    cell: j
                };
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or more simple:

```
function getRowCellPosition(cell) {
    return {
        row: cell.parentNode.rowIndex,
        cell: cell.cellIndex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a for loop that goes through each row and column and compare the TD in that index against the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for row:

```
Array.slice(el.parentNode.parentNode.children).indexOf(el.parentNode)
```

for col:

```
Array.slice(el.parentNode.children).indexOf(el)
```

The slice magick is because `el.parentNode.children` is not an array.

edit: I wasn't aware of `td.cellIndex` and `tr.rowIndex`. Definitely use them.